# I can't get SSL certificates in Python

Tags: python, ssl, homebrew

I'm learning web scraping with Python on Mac OS.
When I run the script it says I need SSL certification.
I've researched and found NO way to solve this.
I've tried somethings which didn't work.

I installed Python via Homebrew and I don't know if this has to do with anything but when I run  `brew doctor` I get this:

> Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
> `./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
> software packages are installed, and which additional flags to use when
> compiling and linking.

Also, when I do `which -a python3`, I get this:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
```

I was thinking deleting the last two Pythons might solve the problem but I haven't found a way to delete this folders. I cannot find the Frameworks folder so I can't delete them.

I've been researching for weeks but still can't solve it. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you are using [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/), have you tried using e.g. `requests.get('some.url', verify=False)` to bypass checking certificates entirely?